# dynamic method name awareness within generic method

Tags: python, dynamic

I would like to create an object in python where a call to any method under it would be routed to a single method implementation. Also the code within this single method should use the name of the method called for processing or for its returned value.

For example, an object where calling any method name under it would print the method name.

```
>>> the_object.a_made_up_method()
You have called method "a_made_up_method"
```

(btw, if [`Mock`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html) could help, I'm all for it)

Comment: Do you know about python decorators?

Comment: @wim - doesn't a decorator require an implementation to decorate? In my case I want to refrain from implementing all the various method calls this object may receive and build a single generic method that replaces all of them

Comment: Right, sorry I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like

```
class My():
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def method():
            print 'You have called method "{}"'.format(name)
        return method

>>> a = My()

>>> a.a_made_up_method()
You have called method "a_made_up_method"
```

Here's another one, seems to work with `*args` and `**kwargs`:

```
class My():
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.method(name)
    def method(self, name):
        def dostuff(*args, **kwargs):
            print "I'm called as {}!".format(name)
            print args, kwargs
        return dostuff
```

Comment: How do the `*args, **kwargs` fit here?

Comment: Also, would this withstand simultaneous multi-threaded calls if there is a blocking component within `method` and the use of `name` is both before and after the blocking component? Notice that each call may have a different `name`...

Comment: @Jonathan I don't think I can answer that off the top of my head :-\ What actually puzzles me in the code I posted is that I can't even use `self` the same way as `name` inside of `method`.

Comment: @Jonathan I added a version that seems to work with `*args` and `**kwargs`. As for multi-threading, you may have to make it a separate question to get an answer.

Comment: @How do `*args`, and `**kwargs` get their values in this case? What about `self`?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost What do you mean "how"? Just call `a.made_up_method(1, 2, foo='bar')`. `self` is a serious problem, because `dostuff` isn't really an instance method and doesn't get `self` as first argument.